# Integer increment and concat with string

Tags: java, auto-increment

I'm in the process of creating a method to generate a unique id, of type Integer, and was wondering how to do the following.

In my Object I want to call the generateUniqueID method from my setter method. The generateUniqueID will generate an incrementing number and then append it to a string

e.g. Reminder-1, Reminder-2 etc....

I'm not quite sure how to do this though and was wondering if anyone could help?

Thank you

Comment: Well, you keep a counter and increment it... which bit are you finding tricky?

Comment: Why not `System.currentTimeMillis()`? Though it'll be a `long`.

Comment: You want a unique identifier for each object you create?

Comment: @adarshr: And multiple invocations can return the same result...

Comment: @Mark Peters - Yes, only provided they happen near-simultaneously. That's why I need to know how much is the concurrency :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>As long as there is no concurrency.</strike>

```
private static int reminderID = 1;

public synchronized static String generateUniqueID() {
    String uniqueId = "Reminder-" + reminderID;
    reminderID++;
    return uniqueId;
}
```

Comment: Assuming you are not running in the clustered environment, or else, you might still end up with same ID.

Comment: @Mark Peters: "As long as there is no concurrency"

Comment: This is the simplest solution that works according to known spec from the OP.

Comment: @Eric that was added after.  Damned grace period.

Comment: It would probably be best to place that method's body in a synchronized block, on the Class object for that class. Otherwise, two nearly-simultaneous calls could overlap in execution and deliver a faulty result.
EDIT: whoops, some comments popped up during typing. I also meant to say it could be a synchronized static method.

Comment: Aside from a synchronized keyword, would adding a `volatile` modifier to `reminderID`, or using `String uniqueId = "Reminder-" + (reminderID++);` also make it thread-safe?

Comment: I don't believe `reminder++` in a single line of code is any more thread-safe, because that is still multiple instructions at the assembly level.

Comment: @Eric: I don't think so; the post-increment operator is not atomic to my knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

```
private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(1);

public String generateUniqueID() {
    return "Reminder-" + counter.getAndIncrement();
}
```

Comment: It should be declared static or IDs will be instance dependant.

Comment: I'm making a new mantra for myself: "first look at java.util.concurrent"!

Answer (score 1):

If you have lot of these you can use base 36 encoding.

```
private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

public String generateUniqueID() {
    return "Reminder-" + Long.toString(counter.incrementAndGet(), 36);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
class Classname {
    private static int highestId = 0;
    int object_id;

    public Classname() {
        object_id = highestId++;
    }
}
```

Would work?

As noted above, this is not threadsafe.

Comment: Except `object` is dangerously close to being a reserved name

Comment: Yeah, it was only meant as an quick example. The first answer here is better. I'll edit the names just to be sure.